# app_offline.htm was not working with No managed code

Tags: app-offline.htm

when I place app_offline.htm in root directory of the website its working fine with CLR version v4
but same not working with CLR version "No managed code"
what could be the issue , please answer my query
My iis version 10.0

Comment: when deployment is happening the site redirects to app_offline.htm in clr version 4.0 but if clr version is no managed code not redirecting to app_offline.htm